# Does atomic.AddInt64() force to fetch/update value from/to main memory?

Tags: go, goroutine

In the below code using `atomic.AddInt64`:

```
func main() {

    // Number of goroutines to use.
    const grs = 2

    // wg is used to manage concurrency.
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(grs)

    // Create two goroutines.
    for g := 0; g < grs; g++ {
        go func() {
            for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
                atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)
            }

            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    // Wait for the goroutines to finish.
    wg.Wait()

    // Display the final value.
    fmt.Println("Final Counter:", counter)
}
```

---

or in below code usng `atomic.LoadInt64`:

```
func writer(i int) {

    // Only allow one goroutine to read/write to the slice at a time.
    rwMutex.Lock()
    {
        // Capture the current read count.
        // Keep this safe though we can due without this call.
        rc := atomic.LoadInt64(&readCount)

        // Perform some work since we have a full lock.
        fmt.Printf("****> : Performing Write : RCount[%d]\n", rc)
        data = append(data, fmt.Sprintf("String: %d", i))
    }
    rwMutex.Unlock()
    // Release the lock.
}

// reader wakes up and iterates over the data slice.
func reader(id int) {

    // Any goroutine can read when no write operation is taking place.
    rwMutex.RLock()
    {
        // Increment the read count value by 1.
        rc := atomic.AddInt64(&readCount, 1)

        // Perform some read work and display values.
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(10)) * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%d : Performing Read : Length[%d] RCount[%d]\n", id, len(data), rc)

        // Decrement the read count value by 1.
        atomic.AddInt64(&readCount, -1)
    }
    rwMutex.RUnlock()
    // Release the read lock.
}
```

---

Does `atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)` or `atomic.LoadInt64(&readCount)` ensure that value of `counter`/`readCount` always refer to main memory but not L1/L2 cache?

Comment: Unlikely, but why do you care?  Even if it's in cache, the hardware is responsible for ensuring that the cache remains consistent between cores.

Comment: The Go spec, and more specifically, the spec of the `atomic` say nothing about "main memory" whatsoever. As far as the spec is concerned, the values could be stored atomically on an antique abacus, or chiseled into a stone tablet a monk, communicated over smoke signals and carrier pigeons.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you might be thinking on a bit wrong level.

Atomic memory operations do not guarantee the values will be "flushed" to/from any memory; they merely guarantee consistency in memory views of multiple concurrently operating CPUs (cores).

That is, if one CPU performs `atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)`, and any other number of CPUs perform `atomic.LoadInt64(&counter)`, it's guaranteed that any of the reading CPUs will either load the value of the `counter` before the 1st CPU incremented it, or after, but not *halfway* in between — say, when the first 32-bit part of the integer was updated but another was not (yet); any atomic load will be guaranteed to either see the increment or not, depending on its total ordering with regard to the update.

Also, if two CPUs happen to issue `atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)` "at the same time", it's guaranteed that by the time the last of these operations completes, the `counter` will be larger by *at least* 2 (provided no other CPUs have atomically decremented that counter at the same time) — that is, it's guaranteed that no increment will be lost due to some sort of the collision, and they will be properly serialized against each other, if needed, in unspecified order.

To reiterate, atomic operations are about consistency; they do not say anything about exactly how this consistency is ensured (and this would be highly hardware-dependent anyway).